# Why QThread.start() doesn't call run?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have the following code(using PySide6):

```
class DoLongProces(QObject):
    finished = Signal()
    def __init__(self,task):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._task=task
        self._realtask=None

    def run(self):
        self._realtask()
        self.finished.emit()

    def start(self,params):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self._realtask= partial(self._task,params)
        self.thread.start()
```

I expect `self.thread.start()` to call run on my QObject. I call it from the gui thread.

This doesn't happen, instead the GUI hangs and the application quits (with 0xC0000409).
Do you know why?

Comment: You cannot expect it to call `run`, as the thread does know anything about it. Add `self.thread.started.connect(self.run)`, *before* `start()`. The "automatic" call to `run` is for QThread subclasses, you're using a QObject that's just *moved* to the thread.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought that is by default. Thanks!

Comment: `run()` is a member of QThread objects just like python's Thread, it's executed for those objects only, and can be overridden to provide custom functions that have to be executed in the thread. `moveToThread` only moves the object to the QThread handler but doesn't do anything else. When the thread is started, the signal is emitted, and the function(s) connected to `started` are executed in the thread of the object they belong to: since the worker has been moved to the same handler (the QThread instance), that function will be executed in that thread. You can call the function as you like.